# Are there the same conclusions in quaternion

Tags: measure-theory, lp-spaces, quaternions, bounded-variation

When I read a parper, there are two lemma in real domain.
[the lemma](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TnLPa.png)

**Definition**: Let $\Omega $ be an open subset of $R^2$. The space of functions of bounded variation
$BV (\Omega ) $is defined as the space of real-valued function $u \in  L^1(\Omega ) $ such that the total variation
$$\int 
_\Omega 
| D_u|  := \sup
\Bigl\{ \int 
_\Omega 
u \operatorname{div}\varphi  \ d x  : \varphi  \in  C^1
_c (\Omega ,R^2), \| \varphi \|_{ L^\infty (\Omega ) }\leq  1
\Bigr\} $$
is finite. Then $BV (\Omega )$ is a Banach space with the norm
$\| u\|_{ BV (\Omega ) }:= \| u\|_{ L^1(\Omega )} +
\int 
_\Omega 
| Du|$ .

**Lemma 1**: Suppose sequence { $u_{n}$} $ \subset  BV (\Omega ) $satisfies sup $\| u_n\|_{ BV (\Omega )} < \infty $. Then there
exist a subsequence$ \{ u_{n_k}\}  $and a function $u \in  BV (\Omega )$ such that
$u_{n_k} \rightarrow  u $ in$\ L^1(\Omega )$ as$\ k \rightarrow  \infty$ .

**Lemma 2**: Assume $\{ u_n\}  \subset  BV (\Omega ) $ and $ u_n \rightarrow  u $in $L^1(\Omega )$. Then
$\int _\Omega | D_u|  \leq  \lim\limits_{n \rightarrow \infty } \inf\int _\Omega 
| D_{u_n}| $.

I want to know if there are similar results in quaternion domain. Also, some relevant references are needed.

Comment: Even when $\Omega \subset \mathbb H^n$, your functions are still real-valued right? I can't see how the quaterion structure is involved in this context.

Comment: They are quaternion-valued.Ω⊂H2, I want to change u into pure quaternion-valued functions.